# Python. Стиль программирования

Tags: python, css

Вопрос очень начального уровня, но интересно мнение со стороны, и возможно советы.

В данный момент я учусь создавать GUI вручную. Появилась одна проблема: после Java привык все называть переменные в CamelCase стиле и давать очень подробные имена (издержка неумения).

К примеру, есть ссылочка на виджет, который представляет собой панель для управлением stack layout (в нем лежат так называемые рабочие модули), и он делает один из рабочих модулей "активным".

Ранее называлось все это безобразие у меня `activeWorkingModuleControlPanel`. Тут я почитал PEP8 и внес коррективы, но не уверен, правильно ли, и улучшил ли я что-то:

```
#WM - working modules
...
panel_control_wm

тип виджета_что делает_над чем делает
```

Хочу разобраться в стилях наименования. Если есть какие-то статьи, в которых были бы разобраны различные варианты, с ПОДРОБНЫМ практическим применением в сложных случаях (когда имя ссылочки должно быть информативным в связи со сложностью системы)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пишете код и в чем-то не уверены, что следуете стандарту - поставьте пакет pep8 - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8. В нем есть скрипт, который указывает на несоответствия стандарту.

Comment: Сопоставить то, что я написал со стандартом я могу, я хотел бы услышать, скорее житейский совет, касательно подобного опыта, и выбранного решения

Comment: У меня подобная проблема также возникала. Впоследствии выбрал для себя следующее правило: если нет зависимости, - пишу по PEP-8, если есть (например, как в wxPython) - следую стилю фреймворка, в данном случае, как и у вас, - camelCase, но, тем не менее, модули не связанные с ГУИ - пишу по PEP-8. То есть для себя выбрал самый удобный способ: не мешать стили в одном модуле.

Comment: Некоторые мысли также когда-то описывал в своем блоге: http://blog.dzinko.org/2011/03/python-pep-8-pep-8.html

Comment: У меня camelCase это просто пережиток общения с Java. Давайте тогда подытожим, с вашей точки зрения, такой PEP8 логичен или все же нет, в моем исполнении. Так-то он вообще мне имена ссылок подсократил где-то в два раза, но со стороны, то есть человека, предположим, которому придется в этом разбираться, будет ли ясна такая запись. Может просто нужно в начале модуля указывать построение имен переменных по типу той расшифровки, что я дал пониже в первом сообщении, типа подстандарт для данного модуля или программы

\# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\# WM - working modules
\# widgetType_functions_object

Answer (score 1):

Вставлю и я свои пять копеек.
На самом деле, все зависит от того, как вы договоритесь с командой и кто ваш проект может поддерживать. И camelCase никакой не пережиток. Всегда более-менее придерживался PEP8, но однажды пришел в большой сложный проект, связанный с ИИ и data mining, который начали и вели бывшие Cишники, т.к. ядро переписывалось с С++ на Python. Все и везде в стиле camelCase, особо хардкорные дяди условия в скобочки оборачивали:) Абсолютно ничего страшного, тут все в дело в том, чтобы все участники использовали одинаковый стиль кода. Даже поймал себя на мысли, что camelCase часто более понятен, `чем_вот_такие_вот_супер_длинные_названия`

Ну и потом, слепо следовать PEP8, наверное, немного глупо. Ну многие ли следуют ограничению в 79 символов в строке? Это актуально для тех, кто пишет для переферийных устройств. Для разработчика под ОС, и, тем более, под веб это нецелесообразно. Мониторы-то у подавляющего большинства больше, чем 19'' :)

Comment: Спасибо за мнение, просто у меня как раз с нижним подчеркиваниями покороче вышло чем в camelCase, но общую суть я понял, что выбор в любом случае за мной и однозначного решения тут нет, а жаль)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ответ на вопрос, однако, вас, например, может заинтересовать [**Google Python Style Guide**](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) в роли некоторой альтернативы `PEP8`.

*Лично мой процесс привыкания к этом стилю прошел совершенно безболезненно и быстро.*