# Как в python лучше писать код?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким регистром писать в python? Змеиным или же верблюжим? Какое написание будет более традиционным?..

Comment: В каждом ЯП есть соглашение как писать. Зайди на оф сайт, почитай что люди пишут. Например сишники ставят скобку открывающую под именем функции и слова подчеркиваниями разделяют. JS разрабы наоборот всё делают - открывают скобку на той же строке и слова кэмелКейсом пишут. Короче, есть conventions. Их не обязательно соблюдать, но желательно. Всё это обычно описывается на оф сайте.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python. Стиль программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/48776/python-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите в консоли python `import this` и там всё будет, если хотите прочитать все более подробно, то `PEP8` в помощь(он есть в интернет в свободно доступе)

Answer (score 0):

PEP8 говорит так:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability. mixedCase is allowed
>   only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style

Comment: Это у вас про функции. А еще есть названия классов, переменных, констант. Классы пишутся верблюжим стилем, с верхней буквы: `class MyClass:`. Переменные пишутся как и функции: в нижнем регистре, разделяя `_`, но переменные константы пишут в верхнем регистре, например: `DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 16`

Comment: Ну если вникать глубоко - то тут вообще от сферы использования, библиотек, сложившихся практик зависит. А так да, согласен с вашими примерами - для общего понимания кода лучше так писать)